# UWP Mi Band 2 Protocol Error

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to take steps from band, but i get ArgumentNullException or ProtocolError. Where is my fault?

```
var characteristic = await GetCharacteristicByServiceUuid(new Guid("0000fee0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"), new Guid("00000007-0000-3512-2118-0009af100700"));
var gattReadResult = await characteristic.Characteristics[0].ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
        // Status is ProtocolError
        Debug.WriteLine(gattReadResult.Status);
```

Comment: What is `GetCharacteristicByServiceUuid` doing? What is the length of `characteristic.Characteristics`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: 1. GetCharacteristicByServiceUuid returns GattCharacteristicsResult object.
2. Length of characteristic.Characteristics is 1.
WTF, now i try to test it, (1:17 o'clock by my time) and it returns status "Success" and 25 steps (like on my band). What is this mean???

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Yes, i try to debug, but yesterday (21.04) it returns ProtocolError. But now (22.04) it's ok. I don't know what was it

Answer (score 0):

After many days understanding, i can say - ProtocolError appears, when band is not paired and not autentified with Application. Problem solved after authentication and synchronization.